# Selenium Grid on virtual machine - how to configure

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, virtualbox, selenium-grid

Hub is configure on physical machine using:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role hub
```

One host is configure using virtual machine (VirtualBox) by:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.122.162:4444/grid/register
```

Hub and host are on the same physical machine.

And now I have a problem when I go to http://192.168.122.162:4444/grid/console
[image]

And when I try run my test cases (with that DesiredCapabilities):

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
            new URL("http://10.0.2.15:5555/wd/hub"), capability);
```

nothing to hapened.

I tried do this on two other physical machines (according to the above steps) and I get:
[image]

And when I try run my test cases:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
            new URL("http://192.168.122.170:5555/wd/hub"), capability);
```

everything is right, tests are run on the host machine.

I read something about configuration VM, about port forwarding, but I cant do this alone. Someone know how to do this? Or maybe this is something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting using below command :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar -role webdriver -hub http://*hub ip*:4444/grid/register -port 8989
```

The error might be because of the undefined port number.

Comment: The error might be because of the undefined port number.